# Track HTTP Referrer

Tags: php, javascript, http, referrer

I have a file called: refdes2.php

```
<script>
  function go(){
    window.frames[0].document.body.innerHTML='<form target="_parent" action="http://www.site.com/refdes3.php"></form>';
    window.frames[0].document.forms[0].submit()
  }    
</script>
<iframe onload="window.setTimeout('go()', 99)" src="about:blank" style="visibility:hidden"></iframe>
```

Then this other file: refdes3.php

```
    <?php
$reftest = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if ($reftest != "") { ?>
<script>
  function go(){
    window.frames[0].document.body.innerHTML='<form target="_parent" action="http://www.site.com"></form>';
    window.frames[0].document.forms[0].submit()
  }    
</script>
<iframe onload="window.setTimeout('go()', 99)" src="about:blank" style="visibility:hidden"></iframe>
<?php

}
else {
?>

<script>
  function go(){
    window.frames[0].document.body.innerHTML='<form target="_parent" action="http://www.site.com/refdes4.php"></form>';
    window.frames[0].document.forms[0].submit()
  }    
</script>
<iframe onload="window.setTimeout('go()', 99)" src="about:blank" style="visibility:hidden"></iframe>
<?php
}
?>
```

But still with google analytics some referrer traffic leaks out to refdes4.php .

I guess a different way to track http referrer ( more accurate like google analytics) could do the thing.

Thank You!

```
if ($reftest != "") { ?>
```

Says that only if the http referrer is blank, it'll allow it to pass. Else nope.

I want it to go 100% clean blank http referrer traffic. ( some browsers don't blank it ).
Currently it's 70% clean traffic. 30% gets leaked.

An alternative to tracking if http referrer is blank (more accurate like google analytics) could be the thing i'm looking for.

Comment: I assume you meant javascript instead of java in your tags. It's also not very clear what you're asking or what problem you're having. You should clarify before the question ends up closed.

Comment: I have edited the question. and thanks for the correction of tag.

Comment: The question still is not really clear. Don’t open the question with 2 massive code-blocks and then bring in google analytics, without explaining anything on your problem or goal. First, give a general idea on what you’re trying to do, then what you did and what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you’re trying to hide the HTTP-Referrer data by using a form, an iframe and its src attribute and javascript?

Well, you are dependant on both then. Browsers may or may not allow setting and overwriting the http referrer with the src attribute of an iframe. You can not hide the referrer in all cases and for 100% sure at all.